# Cell not completely colored

Tags: multirow, multicolumn, colortbl, cell

As some other people over here, I have some troubles having the cells of my table colored properly. I read many threads about this on the forum, but all problems I could find were related to the combination of \makecell and \colortbl.

In my case, I am not using \makecell at this place (I have use the package on other places so I have it loaded) and still have the same problem. But as I am not using this command, the given solutions do not work for me.

The problem is the white gap in the cell with letter "A"
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Risico-inschatting en -analyse}
    \label{tabelRisico-inschatting}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{LightSteelBlue}\arraybackslash}c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm}|>{\columncolor{LightSteelBlue}\arraybackslash}c|l|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{SteelBlue}&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Risico-inschatting}}&&\\
        \cline{2-5}
        \cellcolor{SteelBlue}\multirow{-2}{1.3cm}{\centering\textbf{Risico- Nr.}} & \cellcolor{SteelBlue}\textbf{S} & \cellcolor{SteelBlue}\textbf{F} & \cellcolor{SteelBlue}\textbf{O} & \cellcolor{SteelBlue}\textbf{A} & \cellcolor{SteelBlue}\multirow{-2}{1.3cm}{\centering\textbf{Risico- index}} & \cellcolor{SteelBlue}\multirow{-2}{6cm}{\textbf{Risico-evaluatie}}\\
        \hline
        1&2&2&3&1&5&Zeer ernstig gevaar. Vereist ontwerpmaatregel.\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Could someone please help me get rid of this white gap? Thanks a lot

Comment: you have forced the width of the SFOA columns but the Risico-inschatting heading is wider than that by the amount shown in white

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code I can't reproduce table as you show in the question. After clean-up your code,  corrected a widths of `multirow` cells and considering  @DavidCarlisle comment, I got:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout). As you can see, your table is much wider the text width.

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Risico-inschatting en -analyse}
    \label{tabelRisico-inschatting}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{LightSteelBlue}\centering}p{11mm}|
                *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.55cm}|}
                     >{\columncolor{LightSteelBlue}\centering}p{14mm}|
                     l|}
        \hline
\rowcolor{SteelBlue}
    & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Risico-inschatting}} &   &   \\
        \cline{2-5}
\rowcolor{SteelBlue}
\multirow{-2}{=}{\centering\textbf{Risico Num.}} 
    & \textbf{S}    & \textbf{F}    & \textbf{O}    & \textbf{A} 
    & \multirow{-2}{=}{\centering\textbf{Risico- index}} 
    & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Risico-evaluatie}}\\
        \hline
1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 5 & Zeer ernstig gevaar. Vereist ontwerpmaatregel.\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You should ensure that the last column is a  `p` type. For example, column specification defined as:

```
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{LightSteelBlue}\centering}p{11mm}|
                *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5.4mm}|}
                     >{\columncolor{LightSteelBlue}\centering}p{14mm}|
                     >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-11mm%
                                                -5.4mm-5.4mm-5.4mm-5.4mm-14mm
                                                -14\tabcolsep-9\arrayrulewidth}|
                    }
```

than table will looks as follows:

[image]

Note, with background colour in tables, you are faced with pdf-viewer artefacts. Not all rules will be visible, unless you zoom in to 200 to 300 per cent!

Answer (score 2):

You may of course use [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) to typeset this table. Then you avoid the PDF-viewer artefact, where rules disappears under the cell colouring. I added the package [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) to have nice caption spacing, and also decreased the margins using [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals). In addition, I reduce the fontsize two grades.

In my opinion, it is better to remove all rules except the horizontal rule under *Risico-inchatting* when you are colourising the background of the cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{cals, url, caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Risico-inschatting en -analyse\label{tabelRisico-inschatting}}

\begin{calstable}[c]

% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*2\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*2\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*2\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*2\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/32*16\relax}
    }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 6

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}


\def\blue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{SteelBlue}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}
\def\lblue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{LightSteelBlue}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


% R1H1
\thead{\footnotesize\bfseries
\brow
    \blue\nc{lrt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Risico-inschatting}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
\erow
%R2H2
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfill Risico- Nr.}
    \cell{S}
    \cell{F}
    \cell{O}
    \cell{A}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfill Risico- index}
    \nc{lrb}\alignL\sc{\vfill Risico-evaluatie}\blue
\erow
\mdseries}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R4B1
\brow
    \lblue\alignC\cell{1}\lblue
    \cell{2}
    \cell{2}
    \cell{3}
    \cell{1}
    \lblue\cell{5}\lblue
    \alignL\cell{Zeer ernstig gevaar. Vereist ontwerpmaatregel.}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my answer!  Regarding to bad visible lines in colored tables I wait on your solution with `cals` package :-) . +1!

Comment: @Zarko Thank you!